# <plugin> not a function

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've been trying to solve this mystery almost 2 hours, this is giving me a headache. I tried 2 plug-ins already and I'm always getting "* is not a function". My code is exactly like examples so I don't know why it's not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>asd</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.scrollTo.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.serialScroll.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('#slider').serialScroll({
                items:'li',
                offset:-230, //when scrolling to photo, stop 230 before reaching it (from the left)
                start:1, //as we are centering it, start at the 2nd
                duration:1200,
                force:true,
                stop:true,
                lock:false,
                cycle:false, //don't pull back once you reach the end
                easing:'easeOutQuart', //use this easing equation for a funny effect
                jump: true //click on the images to scroll to them
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="slider">
        <ul>                
            <li><img width="500" height="500" src="dummy/dummy.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
            <li><img width="500" height="500" src="dummy/dummy1.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
            <li><img width="500" height="500" src="dummy/dummy2.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
            <li><img width="500" height="500" src="dummy/dummy3.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>     
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I must be missing something essential there because I see nothing what's wrong.
I'm using jQuery 1.4.2. and there are plug-ins I've tried - [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider), [jQuery serial scroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the `src` attribute in these two lines:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.scrollTo'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.serialScroll'></script>
```

Should end with `.js`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.scrollTo.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='serial/jquery.serialScroll.js'></script>
```

Comment: I must have deleted them while editing... But no, this made no difference. Thanks for noticing though.

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it "* is not a function", or is there something else in place of "*"?

Comment: c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function

Line 143
It was giving this error, so I added this function, which was in the demo jQuery.easing.easeOutQuart = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
 return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
};
But now it just loads - no error, no nothing.

Comment: @bah - Try loading jQueryUI before the plugins. It adds some easing options. Perhaps one of the plugins relies on it. http://jqueryui.com Or just delete the `easing:'easeOutQuart'` line in your code and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, still no action, nothing. I can't imagine what's wrong.

Comment: I assume you deleted that line, and you're still getting an error? What does the error say now?

Comment: Yep, I deleted that line, still nothing. It just loads, no error.

Comment: Well, that's progress. I'm not that familiar with the plugin. I'd say pare it down to something simple and review the docs. If there's no error, then it is likely a configuration issue. Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for trying to help. I'll be trying to write my own plug-in like this on my own probably, that way I might learn how it works.